# Call UIViewController from "subview"

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, view, navigation

I have a UIViewController which when it loads it loads up this..

```
MapViewController *mapController = [[MapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MapView" bundle:nil];
    self.mapViewController = mapController;
    [self.view insertSubview:mapController.view atIndex:0];
    [mapController release];
```

I also have a switch views button that can change to a table view....

```
if (self.tableViewController ==nil)
    {
        TableViewController *tableController = [[TableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TableView" bundle:nil];
        self.tableViewController = tableController;
    [tableController release];
    //[self.view insertSubview:detailController atIndex:0];
    }

    if (self.mapViewController.view.superview == nil)
    {
        [tableViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
        [self.view insertSubview:mapViewController.view atIndex:0];
    }
    else
    {
        [mapViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
        [self.view insertSubview:tableViewController.view atIndex:0];
    }
```

I am trying to change the view to a detail view based on selecting a row in the table view and I cannot work out how to call it at all.  All methods I have seem to fail!  Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the UITableViewDelegate protocol to your controller class.

```
@interface myTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate>
```

When you create your table veiw controller set its delegate to be your controller using:

```
myTableViewController.delegate = self; // Assuming your setup code runs within the table view controller
```

In your tableViewController, implement didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
int rowSelected = [indexPath indexAtPosition:0]; // Assuming your UITableView has a single section.
```

Comment: Wouldn't you do indexPath.row to set rowSelected?

Comment: Oh didn't see the comment about the single section there.

Comment: Thanks guys!  That worked well, it also turns out I had a SwitchViewController too!

Answer (score 0):

The class you should look at for handling row selection is UITableViewDelegate, which has the method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```